# when I use CController::afterAction(), is there any way to klnow the result of the execution of the action, I mean failed or successed

Tags: yii

Here is my code :

```
    class TestController extends Controller {
        public function accessRules() {
            return CMap::mergeArray(
                array(
                    array('allow', 'actions' => array('create'), 'roles' => array('SR001')),
                ),
                parent::accessRules()
            );
        }

    public function afterAction($action) {
        // Here 
    }
}
```

is there any way to know whether it successed or failed ?

Comment: What do you mean the action was succeeded or failed? You can create a local variable into the Controller to set `true` or `false` (`$this->resultAction`), then on your method `afterAction` you check it.

Comment: thank you, It's a good idea. merci